# Replicate form select box by array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

one last doubt, the foreach is not print in the box

The foreach is outside of the table when is in the middle of the code.

[image]

The option values on the table are empty, when is printing outside of the table.

[image]

```
$options = array( "0.00","0.05","0.10","0.15","0.20","0.25","0.30","0.35","0.40","0.45","0.50","0.55","0.60","0.65","0.70","0.75","0.80","0.85","0.90","0.95","1" ); // ◄■■ OPTIONS ARE STATIC (ALWAYS THE SAME).

        $table = $table."</tr>";

        for($i = 0 ; $i <$uCount ; $i++ ){
        $table = $table."<tr><td>".$utilizador[$i]."</td>";

        for($j=0;$j<$carCount;$j++){
        $val= htmlspecialchars($s2[$j], ENT_HTML5 | ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

        $table = $table."<td>"."<select name=\'corp_resp&{$row_menuid['menuId']}&{$_SESSION['UtilizadorID']}&{$dateTime}&{$toEchosave}'.$val.'_'.$utilizador[$i].'\>";
        foreach ($options as $opt)
        {
               echo "<option value='$opt'>$opt</option>\n";
               echo "</select>\n"."</td>";
          }
        }
    $table = $table."</tr>";
}
$table = $table."</form>";
echo $table;
```

Comment: Can u explain in detail what you want in

Comment: Array have 4 positions, i want to count or recognise that positions by the name example Renault and clone that form, depends of the number of positions. If is 2 will reply 2 if is 6 will reply 6 times that form.

Comment: You are looking for how to loop php array I guess. https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_array_num_loop

Comment: @Samarth, i don´t want the loop of the array. I want to take the array and replicate the form according the array.

Comment: you are echoing options before the table is created that's why options are not printed inside the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey are you looking for something like this.Please let me know if it helps.

** Suggested Edit in your code

Change this block of your code

```
foreach ($options as $opt)
{
     echo "<option value='$opt'>$opt</option>\n";
     echo "</select>\n"."</td>";
}
```

to

```
 foreach ($options as $opt)
 {
      $table = $table."<option value='$opt'>$opt</option>\n";
 }
 $table = $table."</select>\n"."</td>";
```

What mistake you are making is that you are printing the options string before even the complete table structure has been created properly.
Just add these options to table variable and print after every processing is done.

So the overall code will now look like

```
  $form = "<form onsubmit=\"return validate();\" id=\"teste\" method=\"post\" action=\"teste.php\">";
  $table = $form."<table><tr><td>Parametro</td>";
  $carCount = count($s2);
  $uCount = count($utilizador);
  for($x = 0; $x < $carCount; $x++){
      $val= htmlspecialchars($s2[$x], ENT_HTML5 | ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
      $table= $table."<td>".$val."</td>";
  }

  $options = array( "0.00","0.05","0.10","0.15","0.20","0.25","0.30","0.35","0.40","0.45","0.50","0.55","0.60","0.65","0.70","0.75","0.80","0.85","0.90","0.95","1" ); // ◄■■ OPTIONS ARE STATIC (ALWAYS THE SAME).

          $table = $table."</tr>";

          for($i = 0 ; $i <$uCount ; $i++ ){
          $table = $table."<tr><td>".$utilizador[$i]."</td>";

          for($j=0;$j<$carCount;$j++){
          $val= htmlspecialchars($s2[$j], ENT_HTML5 | ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

          $table = $table."<td>"."<select name=\'corp_resp&{$row_menuid['menuId']}&{$_SESSION['UtilizadorID']}&{$dateTime}&{$toEchosave}'.$val.'_'.$utilizador[$i].'\>";
          foreach ($options as $opt)
          {
                 $table = $table."<option value='$opt'>$opt</option>\n";
            }
             $table = $table."</select>\n"."</td>";
          }
      $table = $table."</tr>";
  }
  $table = $table."</form>";
  echo $table;
```

Comment: Almost there, the only diference is you are creating your select option and i want to do inside echo("<tr>
 <td align=\"center\" bgcolor='FFFFFF'>$utilizador</td>
 
 <td align=\"center\" bgcolor='FFFFFF'>$form<td>
 


 
");

Comment: It depends on how you want to display it on html. If you want to display differently you have to make those tweaks accordingly. Can you put little bit more details in the question regarding html of the page you want and options value coming from what data source. Is options in the select are static or dynamic ?

Comment: edit another time the post for you understand what i want totally to do. Thank you for help until now.

Comment: @ChristopheCosta hey can you check now if it helps.

Comment: that is very good. I don´t have time to check that now. On the night i will check then i tell you the feedback. Thank you.

Comment: the new update in the post. The values i want to put in the table are working well but put in the table are not, like you see in the picture.

Comment: @ChristopheCosta I don't see use of while loop instead just replace the code block with my updated code block as I am using $s2 directly which contains your cars array and it will print headers as well for you.

Comment: what is wrong for the print of the array be outside of table? @Samarth

Comment: @ChristopheCosta Please check if it helps and solves your problem.